# npm recursive install bower dependencies

Tags: json, node.js, npm, installation, bower

I have multiple node modules developed by myself stored on a private gitlab server. In my Project, i install those modules with bower, so my Project structure Looks like this:

```
appname
    bower_components
        module1
            ...
            package.json
        module2
        ...
     node_modules
     ...
     package.json
```

When i call npm install only the dependencies from the package.json file located in the Folder "appname" will be installed. The Problem is, that my modules, which i install with bower, also have dependencies, which are not listed in the package.json in the root Folder. How can i install those dependencies without installing them globally? It should by something like `npm install bower_components\module1`. I also tried to use the command line Option `--prefix` but it only copies the Folder inside the node_modules Folder.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I imagine that the easiest solution might be to just ditch bower entirely and just install those private modules with `npm`, since those modules apparently have dependencies on other `npm` modules. Otherwise you could try running `npm install` from within each of those module directories.

Comment: but if i run `npm install`inside each node module npm will install the dependencies inside the node module itself, not in the root directory...

Comment: there seems to be an issue in my package.json of my own node modules. The dependencies were saved as dev-dependencies. If I save the necessary dev-dependencies as normal dependencies and run `npm install bower_components\module1` npm will install the dependencies which are saved in the "dependecies"